# Calculating gauge propagator in minimally coupled, non-relativistic fermion system

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, fermions, greens-functions, propagator

For context, I am trying to derive Eq. 4.1 of [$T_c$ superconductors">this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.46.5621). Consider the action

$$S[\psi^\dagger, \psi, a] = -\int d\tau \int d^2r \sum_\sigma \psi^\dagger (D_0-\mu_F-\frac{1}{2m_F}\sum_jD_j^2)\psi$$

where $\mu_F$ is the chemical potential, and $D_\mu = \partial_\mu + ia_\mu$ is the covariant derivative.

I know that I should be able to find an effective action for $a$ by integrating out the fermionic degrees of freedom in the path integral,

$$S_{eff}[a] = Tr\ln(D_0-\mu_F-\frac{1}{2m_F}\sum_jD_j^2) = Tr\ln(-G_0^{-1}) + Tr\ln(G_0\cdot (1 + ia_0 + \frac{1}{2m} \sum_j (ia_j\partial_j + i\partial_j a_j - a_j^2))$$
where $G_0$ is the Green function of the free fermion system ($G_0^{-1} = \partial_\tau -\mu_f -\frac{\nabla^2}{2m}$).

If I expand the second term to second order (dropping powers of $a^3$ or higher), I know this should allow me to find the propagator of the gauge field $a$. Schematically, this should be
$$Tr\ln(G_0\cdot (1-M) = -Tr(G_0M) - \frac{1}{2}Tr(G_0MG_0M).$$

In this case, I think I can write
$M_{r,r'} = (ia_0 + \frac{1}{2m} \sum_j (ia_j\partial_j + i\partial_j a_j - a_j^2)) \delta_{r,r'}$, but **I'm not sure how to deal with the spatial derivatives as matrix elements**.

However, when I actually try to calculate this, I fail to see the following:

1. Why do terms like $Tr(G_0 ia_0)$ and $Tr(G_0 a_j \partial_j)$ vanish?
2. How do the spatial and temporal parts of $a$ decouple? Why should cross-terms like $Tr(G_0 a_0 G_0 a_j\partial_j)$ vanish?
3. How can I relate the derivative terms to the current? In particular, how does $Tr(G_0 (ia_i \partial_i + i\partial_i a_i) G_0  (ia_j \partial_j + i\partial_j a_j)$ end up as $<J_i J_j>$? If I understand correctly, these partial derivatives aren't actually acting on the Green functions because they are just matrix elements...

I feel like I'm just making stupid mistakes, but I would love to see how to resolve this.

Comment: To deal with spatial derivatives, you could make a Fourier transformation and work in k space, where the spatial derivatives will then be diagonal and just k.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have also tried working out the trace in Fourier space ($k$ and $\omega$), but I then encounter a different problem: I am not sure how to relate the Green functions in k-space to the current in k-space.